# An issue with recieving List of Objects from Room database through Dao, Repository and Viewmodel. Cannot find mistake

Tags: java, android, mvvm, android-room, android-viewmodel

I have methods in Dao, in Repository, in ViewModel and in Activity to get list of Persons,
but I get empty list in the end (Null object reference error).
WHere can be a mistake? THanks a lott..

In PersonDao:

```
@Dao
public interface PersonDao {
    //other methods of PersonDao

    @Query("SELECT * FROM person_table WHERE status = :status ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 5")
    List<Person> getFivePersonsFrom(String status);
}
```

In PersonRepository:

```
public class PersonRepository {
    private PersonDao mPersonDao;
    private List<Person> mFivePersonsFrom;

    //other methods

    List<Person> getFivePersonsFrom(String status) {
        PersonRoomDatabase.databaseWriteExecutor.execute(() -> {
            mPersonDao.getFivePersonsFrom("noob");
        });
        return mFivePersonsFrom;
    }
}
```

In PersonViewModel:

```
public class PersonViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private PersonRepository mRepository;
    public List<Person> mFivePersonsFrom;
    public PersonViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        mRepository = new PersonRepository(application);
        mFivePersonsFrom = mRepository.getFivePersonsFrom("noob");
        //other methods
    }
    public List<Person> getFivePersonsFrom() {
        mRepository.getFivePersonsFrom("noob");
        return mFivePersonsFrom;
    }  
}
```

In MainActivity:

```
private CardStackView noobCardStackView;
private NoobAdapter noobAdapter;
List<Person> noobList;     
// other
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    noobViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this,
            ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(this.getApplication()))
            .get(PersonViewModel.class);
    noobList = noobiewModel.getFivePersonsFrom();
noobAdapter = new NoobAdapter(new NoobAdapter.NoobDiff(), noobList); 
    noobCardStackView.setAdapter(noobAdapter);
    // methods
}
```

Comment: the simplest explanation would be that there are no persons with status "noob" in the database. Is your database a singleton? Maybe you insert persons in other instance of the database then the one you read from?

Comment: when I used LiveData<List<Person>> getNoobs - it worked, but now I dont need Livedata for this List of 5 random noobs. I tried to get List<Person> and I get null. Seems like there is some difference between how I need to catch both of them, apart from not writing "LiveData<>" and not puting  in PersonRepository() method. But I cannot find the mistake

Comment: OK, then it's probably that you try to use the list before it gets fetched from the DB, I don't see any async processing in your code. It worked with LiveData because it handled waiting for the result. You can test it by adding a delay before passing noobList to noobAdapter

Comment: "Executor" in PersonRepository directs the task to another thread but not the main, as I understand (the same I use with @update method for example). Now, when I add in PersonRepository(Application application): "mFivePersonsFrom = mPersonDao.getFivePersonsFrom("noob"), there is another mistake: "Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time."